# Movilizer: How to disable the column head in a table screen?

Tags: mobile, movilizer

I want to create a table by using a Table screen and the table should not include a column head.

However, if the Table screen does not include Answers with `dummyAnswer="true"`, the screen is invalid.

Is there another possibility to create a table without a column head?

Comment: Please, provide more info: Which mobile platform are you using? Which developer toolkit? As this is currently, you will hardly get an answer.

Comment: As indicated in the title of the post the platform is Movilizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the column header row by leaving all Answers in the column head empty. This means you have to make sure they do not contain a text attribute with a value ... all of them. If this is the case the header will not be displayed.

Comment: Hi André, thanks for your help. I tried it and it works fine.